# Simple Login System Issues

Tags: php

So I'm learning how to make a simple login system for a website I'm making and I'm getting this error.

Notice: Use of undefined constant myusername - assumed 'myusername' in /home/dkitterm/public_html/index.php on line 4

These are lines 3-6.

```
    session_start();
    if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
     header("location: main_login.php");
    }
```

This is my check login page as well.

```
        <?php

    $host="localhost";
    $username="dkitterm";
    $password="";
    $db_name="";
    $tbl_name="members";

    //connect to server and db
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("Server Down");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

    //username and password sent from form
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

    //debunk
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    //encrypt password
    $encrypted_mypassword=md5($mypassword);


    $sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE login='$myusername' and password='$encrypted_mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

    if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file                 "login_success.php"
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword"); 
    header("location: index.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you'd better throw this whole code away as soon as possible. it's terrible one

Comment: I'm just learning man. I assume you started out somewhere too. Just looking for some help here.

Comment: I do understand that it isn't your code. You are just got it somewhere to learn from. **That's why** I told you to get rid of it as soon as possible. You will get no good from this code. Find yourself a better one.

Comment: Also, no idea why this needed to be downvoted when all I was doing was asking a question. Forgive me for trying to learn something.

Comment: I do believe that questions with less reputation have less relevance in the search. Thus, this code less likely would be found by some poor victim. It isn't you downvoted personally, but a question. Nobody is blaming you for asking it.

Comment: I'll think twice before using this site again if it's going to be filled with elitist jerks like yourself. You didn't even try to point me in a better direction. You just come in here and start whining about how bad the code is and start downvoting everything.

Comment: I am not downvoting everything. But only bad codes. It seems you are taking these virtual points too personal. Relax, please. It won't break your life.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all your check page doesn't protect you 100% so you need 
to

```
session_start();
    if(!session_is_registered("myusername")){
     header("location: main_login.php");
     die(); 
    }
```

and put quotations around myusername otherwise it will treat it as a constant which its not

Comment: Although your answer is technically correct, this code shouldn't be used anyway. It was deprecated in the last century.

Comment: when i need to improve his answer i should re-implement the login

Comment: Also, Col. Shrapnel, instead of coming across as a jerk, why don't you suggest something useful instead? Where do you suggest I look if you are so wise?

Comment: I will. Says I have to wait 1 minute.

Comment: That's why I call this site evil. instead of being a source of knowledge it actually being source of ignorance and bad practices. just for the "it solve his problem" reason. And a handful of reputation points.

Comment: I completely agree you but since your first comment you should help 
and its obvious that you have knowledge more than me in this field if I see a good answer for a question I will not answer it again except if i want to improve it , so if you answered that before i will read your answer and vote you up for the new information

Answer (score 2):

As @Col. Sharpanel said this is another better solution because you used a depreciated function.

```
 session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
     header("location: main_login.php");
    }

  <?php

$host="localhost";
$username="dkitterm";
$password="";
$db_name="";
$tbl_name="members";

//connect to server and db
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("Server Down");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

//username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

//debunk
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

//encrypt password
$encrypted_mypassword=md5($mypassword);


$sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE login='$myusername' and password='$encrypted_mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file                 "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername; 
//if you need to register the password do the same but for the password 
header("location: index.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```